# Disable multinput when scan using barcode scanner

Tags: jquery, barcode-scanner

I am using a barcode scanner to input a text field in a html / jquery form.

I keep cursor on input field and scan using barcode scanner and upc display in field.

The problem is sometime product boxes has more then one barcode so scanner quickly scan more then one barcode and display as string .
for example first code is 123456 and second is 222333 then in input box they display as 123456222333.

any help in this?

I have tried that if input box has somthing then it should not allow more input like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#pr_id").keypress(function(){
      var inp = $(this).val();
      if(inp != ''){
         e.preventDefault(); 
        return false;
      }
    }); 
});
```

but its not working ok.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: do you have the part of the code where scanner insert value in the input ?

Comment: What is length of your possible barcode?

Comment: this can veries from 6 to 12 or 15 , not sure about it. May be use a time delay in next input can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add checking the length of inputted barcode, for example if it has a static length equal 6:

```
$("#pr_id").keypress(function(){
  var inp = $(this).val();
  if(inp != '' && inp.length == 6){
   /*  e.preventDefault(); 
       return false;*/
  }
});
```

Or if it has a range length, for example from 6 to 8:

```
$("#pr_id").keypress(function(){
  var inp = $(this).val();
  if(inp != '' && inp.length >= 6 && inp.length <= 8){
    /* e.preventDefault(); 
       return false;*/
  }
});
```

I can't understand why you'd used (you need edit `.keypress(function(e)` cause `e` will be not defined)

```
e.preventDefault(); 
return false;
```

Here should be some logic that would allow you to do something with your barcode, I think so.